# Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab installation error MATLAB R2018a

Tags: matlab, bayesian-networks

I am getting an error when trying to test Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab, I am doing the same as the installation shown here but get errors (for MATLAB 2018a):  I changed the ffa.m and mfa.m file for isfinite and when I tried to change the name of function CPD_to_CPT in the files mentioned in the  error the situation got worse and nothing was calculated at all and the error still remained.

```
>> test_BNT

ll =

   1.0e-10 *

    0.2822    0.1697

cycle 1 lik -51.5585 
cycle 2 lik -45.0863 
cycle 3 lik -42.9953 
EM iteration 1, ll = -51.5585
EM iteration 2, ll = -45.0863
EM iteration 3, ll = -42.9953

EM iteration 1, ll = -81.0153
EM iteration 2, ll = -67.2658
EM iteration 3, ll = -60.1511
EM iteration 4, ll = -56.6276
EM iteration 5, ll = -54.9433

100 samples, 1dp 1, 2dp 0, 3dp 0,  err 0.070767
200 samples, 1dp 1, 2dp 0, 3dp 0,  err 0.052974
300 samples, 1dp 1, 2dp 0, 3dp 0,  err 0.058912
400 samples, 1dp 1, 2dp 1, 3dp 0,  err 0.018224
500 samples, 1dp 1, 2dp 1, 3dp 0,  err 0.015127

cycle 1       log likelihood -94.4095 
cycle 2       log likelihood -73.8294 
cycle 3       log likelihood -67.4196 

EM iteration 1, ll = -94.4095
EM iteration 2, ll = -73.8294
EM iteration 3, ll = -67.4196

EM iteration 1, ll = -322.9274
EM iteration 2, ll = -48.2780
EM iteration 3, ll = -44.9882
EM iteration 4, ll = -39.3452
EM iteration 5, ll = -31.8845

mixexp2: loglik before learning -322.927442, after 5 iters -31.884507

ans =

    0.6785

Cycle    1  Error   37.305788
Cycle    2  Error   19.821065
Cycle    3  Error   19.801395
Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded
EM iteration 1, ll = -37.3058
EM iteration 2, ll = -19.8211
EM iteration 3, ll = -19.8014


mpe =

  1×6 cell array

    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}


mpe =

  1×6 cell array

    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}


mpe =

  1×6 cell array

    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}


mpe =

  1×6 cell array

    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}


mpe =

  1×6 cell array

    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}

Elapsed time is 0.004768 seconds.
Error: File: CPD_to_CPT.m Line: 36 Column: 16
Function with duplicate name "CPD_to_CPT" cannot be defined.

Error in discrete_CPD/convert_to_pot (line 14)
CPT1 = CPD_to_CPT(CPD);

Error in jtree_inf_engine/enter_evidence (line 57)
      pot{n} = convert_to_pot(bnet.CPD{e}, pot_type, fam(:), evidence);

Error in qmr1 (line 84)
tic; [engine{2}, ll(2)] = enter_evidence(engine{2}, big_evidence); toc

Error in test_BNT (line 23)
qmr1
```

Comment: Have you asked the authors in the github repository? that is the likely place for you to get answers

Comment: Yes, I have asked on the github repository too.